# Actual weights on Lifefitness FSF3 machine

Tags: machine

The gym in my new building finally opened, and it uses the LifeFitness Fit Series Fit 3 machine. I haven't worked out in ages, and I'm trying to figure out what I was actually lifting, given that the plates are labelled simply 1-21. The sales materials and manuals I've found online say that the range is 5 kg at the easiest setting to 95 kg at the heaviest. I'm not sure how that translates into weights per increment, though. Is the easiest 1 - or is it no pin at all and just the impedance of the machine? If setting 1 = 5 kg, then that means each of the plates under it (and plate 1 is the smallest) are 4.5 kg or very nearly 10 lb. Those are nice round numbers - but I'm still not sure that's right, so if I were doing lat pulls on setting 6, I'm pulling down 27.5 kg or 60 lbs?

I can't calibrate off what it 'feels' like because I haven't been inside a gym in almost six months.

Apologies if there is something obvious I'm missing, and any help most appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a question you should be asking the people that manage/own your building.  They should be able to provide what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with what you have outlined. It really doesn't matter unless you are switching between free weights or some other machines. The suggestion of the luggage scale would be most accurate, but rather time consuming for a novice lifter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).